# Scilab 2023.0.0 VISA Atoms Modul

Tags: scilab, visa

how can I install the VISA Modul in Scilab 2023.0.0 ?

Scilab 6.0.2 is working and installed automaticly atomsInstall('visa')

I get following Error:

```
--> atomsInstall('visa')
atomsInstallList: The package "visa" is not registered.
Please check on the ATOMS repository that it is available for Scilab 2023.0 on Windows.
If it is, run atomsSystemUpdate() before trying atomsInstall(..) again.

bei Zeile    52 von Funktion atomsError       ( C:\Users\kwas\AppData\Local\scilab-2023.0.0\modules\atoms\macros\atoms_internals\atomsError.sci Zeile 66 )
bei Zeile    78 von Funktion atomsInstallList ( C:\Users\kwas\AppData\Local\scilab-2023.0.0\modules\atoms\macros\atoms_internals\atomsInstallList.sci Zeile 117 )
bei Zeile   240 von Funktion atomsInstall     ( C:\Users\kwas\AppData\Local\scilab-2023.0.0\modules\atoms\macros\atomsInstall.sci Zeile 256 )


--> atomsSystemUpdate()
Scanning repository https://atoms.scilab.org/2023.0/TOOLBOXES/64 ... Done
```

Can you guide me, how to install it, using the zip file downloaded from

https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/visa

I tried

```
--> atomsInstall("C:\Users\kwas\Downloads\visa_0.9.1-2.bin.x64.windows.zip")
bei Zeile   177 von Funktion atomsInstall ( C:\Users\kwas\AppData\Local\scilab-2023.0.0\modules\atoms\macros\atomsInstall.sci Zeile 193 )

Ungültiger Index.
```

Answer (score 1):

The VISA toolbox is based on compiled (closed) source code and is not compatible with the latest version of Scilab:
https://scilab.discourse.group/t/instrument-control/61

Comment: Thank you, but this issue is popping up even with Scilab 6.0.2 and 6.1